# Difference between JSONB PostgreSQL and NoSQL systems?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nosql

I would to understand the difference between PostgreSQL JSONB and NoSQL systems such as MongoDB or Hbase.

I would also some uses cases.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is a [relational database management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) that has a data type `jsonb` which can be manipulated with SQL functions efficiently. Like in all RDBMS, SQL is used as language to communicate with the database server.

NoSQL is an umbrella term for a number of different database systems which use other languages than SQL to communicate with the database server. It is hard to generalize, but often the emphasis is more on speed than on consistency.

It's even harder to say something universally valid about use cases, but maybe NoSQL is more useful when you have to deal with data that cannot reasonably be represented in a table.